# django display specific data from model in templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Model:

```
class Exercise (models.Model):
    name_e = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Subject (models.Model):
    name_s = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise)
```

View:

```
exercise_all = Exercise.objects.all()
subject_all = Subject.objects.all()
```

My SQL table contain subjects and exercises connected via ForeignKey

I pass view variables as a context to the template:

```
{% for e_field in exercise_all %}
<table>
<tr><th>Header</th></tr>
    {% for s_field in subject_all %}
    <tr><td>{{ e_field.name_e }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

If I have, let's say, 3 types of Exercises and 10 Subjects connected with Exercises (subject1->exercise1, subject2->exercise1, subject3->exercise1, subject4->exercise2 etc.)
I want to display 3 tables in a template and each table will display only tr/subjects corresponding to table/exercise. I tried with {% if ... in ... %} but maybe i should do some function in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should be able to say:

```
{% for e_field in exercise_all %}
<table>
<tr><th>Header</th></tr>
    {% for s_field in e_field.subject_set.all %}
    <tr><td>{{ e_field.name_e }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: shouldn't be s_field.name.e instead of e_field ?

Comment: Probably. I copied it from your example.